# why does main() compile in g++ compiler, but not in Visual studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, g++

Why does the following code works perfectly on a g++ compiler, but gives error on Visual Studio IDE?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
  cout <<"this is a test"<<
  return 0;
}
```

In visual studio, I have to change code to the following:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout <<"this is a test"<<
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you see any messages from g++? What version are you using? It is recommended to run it with additional arguments like `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Weffc++ -Werror -std=c++11` (or c++14)

Comment: Alsi try avoid cutting the entire right galdf of your code when you copy and paste.

Comment: I do not see any messages from c++, i think the version is 5-4.0, when i run on IDE i get the error "missing type specifier - int"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default configuration of GCC compiler is notorious for allowing non-standard features (kept for misguided "backward compatibility" with anscient code) to leak into C and even into C++ code.

If you prefer to write your code in standard C or C++ language, make sure to use such compiler settings as `-pedantic` or, better, `-pedantic-errors` as well as the appropriate `-std=...` setting. These options are not perfect, but they will make the compiler to catch the majority of basic errors.

Comment: As opposed to VC++ which doesn't have _any_ non-standard features, like binding non-const references to temporaries ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The first program is invalid  C++, but since this style of function definition (with no explicit return type) was once common in C, g++ lets you get away with it by default for sake of backwards compatibility. Visual Studio doesn't do this.

If you want g++ to keep strict standard compliance (you should), use

```
g++ -pedantic -std=c++11 (or -std=c++14)
```

This should flag your program as invalid with a warning message. It is not enough to use just `-std=c++xx`. Always use both options.

It is also advisable to enable various additional warning messages, for example:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++
```

*-Weffc++ can give you false positives, see discussion in comments*

Warnings should never be ignored, but if you want the compiler to enforce this, the following recommended option makes it treat all warnings as errors:

```
g++ -Werror
```

Comment: `-Weffc++` is based on the first edition of Effective C++, so is not useful for modern C++ code. I don't recommend using it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely what specific warnings from -Weffc++ set are not useful for modern code? I can't think of any.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55837 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16166 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16168 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77984 (it might be nice if somebody fixed it, but until then it's unhelpful)

Comment: That's my point: there are several unfixed bugs in -Weffc++ and that makes it unhelpful in too many cases. A warning that produces more noise than signal is not a good warning.

Comment: @JonathanWakely It looks like 55837 and 77984 are triggered by perfectly good C++03 code, and I remember myself just putting `: string1(), string2()` in a ctor to silence 55837 back when. Never encountered 77984 IRL but it also looks like it's relevant in C++03 mode. Cannot reproduce 16168.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139877/discussion-between-jonathan-wakely-and-n-m).